# When Bluemix service "Connect & Compose" will be up?

Tags: ibm-cloud, connect-compose

Bluemix service "Connect & Compose" is down for few days now. 
Will this service be available soon ?

Answer (score 1):

I am able (right now) to create, open, edit and save with "Connect & Compose" in US region. It seems the service works normally now.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the 'Connect and Compose' down in all three regions (a beta version is still working for the development team). You can check the status of the Bluemix platform and its services here: https://status.ng.bluemix.net/